# Mac CSS background display issue

Tags: css, safari

I have a site that gets a display issue when displayed on a mac with safari. The background should be grey throughout, but only displays from half way down the page. I only have a windows so cannot recreate the problem to inspect it. I have this image sent from a client, the website is [this](http://carnationleasing.com)

Could some one explain why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: What is the resolution that you've tried before?

Comment: And provide some CSS please...

Comment: That is super weird. As soon as I open the developer tools to try figure it out, the white background goes away. And the way you are doing your CSS, it does not make sense for it appear white only where it does. Its some sort of weird style calculation error. 

Maybe try only setting the background color on the body only for the grey color. instead of there and the child elements? just a guess, never seen anything like that.

Comment: I was adding a background colour to the child elements to try and stop this happening, is a really strange thing, thanks for checking though.